# Epson POS printer - Automatic Status Back Specification

Tags: point-of-sale, epson

I'm trying interpret the Automatic Status Back (ASB) data from Epson POS printer. I've successfully made contact with the printer using some example code from the UB-E20 Technical Reference Guide (www.amigopos.com/faq/faq_262.aspx). Unfortunately, the manual only states where I can expect the 4 bytes of ASB data in the return string from my query. It does not explain what each bits represents in those 4 bytes. I can see that the return values change when I open the cover of the printer and/or remove paper, but I want to be certain that I am looking for the proper values for the different failure modes.

I've tried contacting Epson, but have had no response. And I cannot seem to find a spec for ASB anywhere on-line. Anyone have any experience with ASB on Epson Printers?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/version-two/downloads/detail?name=ESC-POS-Command-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem a few months ago, but talking with some guys from Epson i made this. This is how to get the Status of the paper
I hope that this will help you.

' **************************************** 
' Format    ASCII       DLE     EOT     n
'           Decimal     16      4       n
' ****************************************
'   n   Function
'   1   Transmit printer status
'   2   Transmit off-line status
'   3   Transmit error status
'   4   Transmit paper roll sensor status
' *****************************************

comPort.Write(Chr(16) & Chr(4) & Chr(4))
Dim aReplyBuffer(0) As Byte
Dim intNBytes As Integer = 0
comPort.Read(aReplyBuffer, 0, 1)

AND THIS IS THE RESPONSE

' Status Response 
'   n       name 
'   0       Error 
'   30      No Paper 
'   18      OK

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Epson directly through their developer network. They had me sign an NDA and now I have the spec. I'm just putting this info up here for anyone who might need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for it you can now find it at:
https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=122