# How to know that the paper is out on EPSON thermal printer, model TM-88IV

Tags: c#, .net, status, epson, thermal-printer

I have EPSON thermal printer, model TM-88IV. I am able to get the various properties of the printer but cannot find any to get the following status:

1. Paper is out
2. Printer is in error state
3. Printer is off

I am using the following code:

```
string printerName = "EPSON";
string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%'", printerName);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
{
    MessageBox.Show(printer.Properties["Name"].Name + " - " + printer.Properties["Name"].Value
        + "\n" +
        printer.Properties["PrinterStatus"].Name + " - " + printer.Properties["PrinterStatus"].Value
        + "\n" +
        printer.Properties["DetectedErrorState"].Name + " - " + printer.Properties["DetectedErrorState"].Value
        + "\n" +
        printer.Properties["ExtendedDetectedErrorState"].Name + " - " + printer.Properties["ExtendedDetectedErrorState"].Value
         + "\n" +
        printer.Properties["ExtendedPrinterStatus"].Name + " - " + printer.Properties["ExtendedPrinterStatus"].Value
        );
}
```

I am getting various values for the above properties but cannot map it to the status of the printer.

The output is

```
Name: EPSON TM-T88IV
PrinterStatus : 3
DetectedErrorState: 0
ExtendedDetectedErrorState: 0
ExtendedPrinterStatus: 2
```

I have installed the EPSON TM-88IV drivers that came in the cd along with the printer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `DetectedErrorState` and `ExtendedDetectedErrorState` show `0` which means **Unknown**. Does that mean this printer doesn't support this property, your current driver doesn't support it, or something else - I don't know. Also your `ExtendedPrinterStatus` shows `2` which means **Unknown**.

Your `PrinterStatus` says `3` which means **Idle** so you can't gather any useful information from this.

Try querying for `PrinterState`. It is a long shot though because this property is marked obsolete, but hey, it's just a line of code, see what would it return.

More info about what each returned value means is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT**
As this printer should support *automatic status back* (**ASB**) notification, you might be able to read that status directly from the printer, not using WMI. [Refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514231/epson-pos-printer-automatic-status-back-specification) for details about ASB. [Here is the specification for your printer](http://www.novopos.ch/client/EPSON/TM-T88IV/TM-T88IV%20Specification/t88ivs_e_g.pdf)

Comment: PrinterState is giving value 0